# How do I tell the index of my subdomain to call the entire contents of the root directory in the index.php file of my sub-directory?

Tags: php

I am fairly new to php but I have an index file in my root directory where I define some php variables and call the "header.php" file which contains my site content.

Here is the structure.

I have two domains

**mysite.com** -> references the root folder, the index file (which contains my dynamic variables)  calls header.php using php includes which loads images, css, and content

**domain1.mysite.com** -> references a sub-directory titled "domain1". In domain1 I have an index file with seperately defined variables and I would like to call the SAME header and content that mysite is calling in the root directory. However, because I am calling it from a sub-directory, it does not load images or CSS.

I think this is a simple fix, but how do I tell the index of my subdomain to call the entire contents of the root directory in the index.php file of my sub-directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using absolute paths in your header.php file, so rather than:

```
<link src="../path/to/file.css" />

<link src="/root/path/to/file.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually won't be able to do it directly the way you are trying because the CSS is above the "top" of the website.  You do have a couple of solutions, however.

1) You can edit your HTML code to reference the main domain, such as:

2) You can copy the CSS to the domain1.mysite.com directory

3) If you plan to change your CSS often, you can avoid having to maintain two directories with the same CSS by creating a "symbolic link" on your server so that it *looks* like there are two directories, but they are really just one.  You will also need to make sure that your web server (probably Apache) has permission to follow links.  Your server administrator can help you will all of this.

4) Depending on the software available on your server, you might also be able to use a PHP script to grab the file.  For example, in your domain1.mysite.com folder, create a PHP script such as:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css;");
include("../style.css");
?>
```

Don't worry if you script file ends in .php instead of .css.  The header will tell the browser that it is a CSS file.

Good luck.